# How can I change URL for some functions in $resource Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There is the following code:

```
angular.module('app.posts.services', []).factory('Post', ['$resource', 'API_ENDPOINT', ($resource, API_ENDPOINT) ->
    $resource(API_ENDPOINT, { id: '@id' }, {
        update: {
            method: 'PUT'
        }
    })
]).value('API_ENDPOINT', 'http://somedomainname.com/users/:user_id/posts/:id')
```

But for the update method I want to change the URL format: "http://somedomainname.com/posts/:id". How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can change the URLs of specific action methods. It's documented in the **[`$resource` documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.27/docs/api/ngResource/service/$resource#usage)** in the actions parameter:

> url – {string} – action specific `url` override. The url templating is
> supported just like for the resource-level urls.

***JavaScript***

```
angular.module('app.posts.services', []).factory('Post', ['$resource', 'API_ENDPOINT', ($resource, API_ENDPOINT) ->
    $resource(API_ENDPOINT, { id: '@id' }, {
        update: {
            method: 'PUT',
            url: 'http://somedomainname.com/posts/:id'
        }
    })
]).value('API_ENDPOINT', 'http://somedomainname.com/users/:user_id/posts/:id')
```

Answer (score 0):

The *angular.value* or *angular.constant* could be used:

*[Providers](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers)*

Comment: I mean I want to change url for delete method only!

Comment: Im not sure if it is valid. RESTful format it is a patter which you should not change. And $resource is a solution for that. I think you should use an "alternative solution for delete". But i think delete URL should be fixed, not your method.